# The entity type <type> is not part of the model from the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I get this error (`An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
The entity type tblMessage is not part of the model for the current context.`) and have tried fixes I found online but they didnt seem to help. I also did somethin similar for another database tabel earlier in the code.

Im trying to retrieve messages form my database table called tblMessages.

Constructor:

```cs
public JsonResult ConversationWithContact(int contact)
        {
            if (Session["UserID"] == null)
            {
                return Json(new {status = "error", message = "User is not logged in"});
            }

            //var currentUser = (Models.tblUser)Session["UserID"];

            var conversations = new List<Models.tblMessage>();

            using (var db = new Models.ChatContext())
            {
                int currentUserId = (int)Session["UserID"];
                var currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);
                conversations = db.Conversations.Where(c => (c.receiverId == currentUser.Id
                                                             && c.senderId == contact) ||
                                                            (c.receiverId == contact
                                                             && c.senderId == currentUser.Id))
                    .OrderBy(c => c.created_at)
                    .ToList();
            }

            return Json(
                new {status = "success", data = conversations},
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            );
        }
```

Context:

```cs
public ChatContext() : base("TrinityEntities")
        {
        }

        public static ChatContext Create()
        {
            return new ChatContext();
        }

        public DbSet<tblUser> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<tblMessage> Conversations { get; set; }
```

Database model class:

```cs
public class tblMessage
    {
        public tblMessage()
        {
            status = messageStatus.Sent;
        }

        public enum messageStatus
        {
            Sent,
            Delivered
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int senderId { get; set; }
        public int receiverId { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public messageStatus status { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is issue with `Table Mapping` to database. each entity will be set up to map to a table with the same name as the `DbSet<TEntity>` property that exposes to the derived context. If no `DbSet<TEntity>` is included for the given entity, the class name is used.
as you set in your code `Users` and `Conversations` is not table name. for that you can customize also refere https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/tables
and use `Data Annotations` for specify table name.

```
 public messageStatus status { get; set; }
```

i think this property is not not part of your table column so you have to specify  `[NotMapped]` Data Annotations.

after changes and adding `Data Annotations` to table context and table look likes.

```
public class ChatContext : DbContext
{
    public ChatContext()
    {

    }
    public virtual DbSet<tblUser> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<tblMessage> Conversations { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
        }
    }
}
```

and your models(tables) entities look like.

```
[Table("tblMessage")]
public class tblMessage
{
    public tblMessage()
    {
        status = messageStatus.Sent;
    }
    public enum messageStatus
    {
        Sent,
        Delivered
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int senderId { get; set; }
    public int receiverId { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public messageStatus status { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime created_at { get; set; }
}

[Table("tblUser")]
public class tblUser
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

now you can access your `Conversations` and `Users` after adding `[Table("<table-name>")]` Data-Annotations.

also you can use `Fluent API` for table mapping.

after using table mapping table after debug code image like.

[image]

i hope it helps you and let me know if require any more information. :)

Comment: DbContextOptionsBuilder is unkown what do I need to include to use this? And do I need to edit this string `Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true`

Comment: as per your code i think you set your connection string just ignore this method because i have used for testing your code :).

Comment: as in your code add Data-Annotations for Table[] and for NotMapped it should works fine i have tried and work successfully :)

Comment: the usesqlserver doenst exist when I use DbContextOptionsBuilder

Comment: if you are used entity framework core then `UseSqlServer` is extension method available on  `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace

Comment: @im-ruben do u have your internal DB context which inherits DbContext? And are you including your entity into db context like below 
```protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
modelBuilder.Entity<tblMessage>());```